# Can't use connected service in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to update my service references in a .net framework project. I can't do it anymore and I get an error saying:

> The current project does not support service reference

I've always been able to do this until today. This seems to be a problem only in vs2019 as I'm not experiencing this in vs2017.

I've tried restarting the program multiple times to no avail. When trying to add new service references I get the error:

> No Connected Service is supported for the current project type.

The project is a class library in 4.6.2

Comment: The problem was fixed by reinstalling vs2019.

Answer (score 3):

As you've seen, you need to install .NET Framework 4.6.2 to open corresponding project. You can install it directly inside VS installer via:

1. Open VS installer (search installer in windows start)
2. Click Modify of your installed VS
3. Switch to 'Individual components'
4. Under node '.NET', select ".NET Framework 4.6.2 SDK" and ".NET Framework 4.6.2 targeting pack"
5. Click 'Modify'

[image]

You can re-open the solution after this installation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You were right that I didn't have the .Net 4.6.2 installed but installing it does not seem to have fixed the problem. Any other suggestions? Is this an issue with vs2019?

Comment: @SkúliÞórÁrnason in Tools---->Options--->Preview Features---- Flag on Use previews of the .Net Core SDK

Comment: @SkúliÞórÁrnason 1) Right click on Service Reference

2) Select Configure Service Reference

3) Uncheck "Reuse types in referenced assemblies"

Comment: The problem is that I can't access Service Reference. When I click Configure Service Reference I get the aforementioned error.

Comment: @SkúliÞórÁrnason 

let's try this way:

1) start visual studio as an administrator, and run the program.
way 2:

set source control plugin to None
go to TOOLS > Options > Source Control.
add service reference
set the source control plugin to the original value

way3:
Go to Debug menu and click on (Options and Settings)
Select Source Control.
Under Current Source ControlPlug-in drop down select none